# How to loop though range and randomly shuffle a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list

Given a list `x = [1,0,0,1,1]`I can use `random.shuffle(x)` repeatedly to shuffle this list, but if I try to do this a for loop the list doesn't shuffle.

For example:

```
x = [1,0,0,1,1]
k = []
for i in range(10):
     random.shuffle(x)
     k.append(x)
return x
```

Basically, `k`contains the same sequence of x unshuffled? Any work around?

Comment: `random.shuffle` is **in place**. You're filling `k` with references to the same list, so all ten lists in the result will be in the same random order. Maybe try a shallow copy, `k.append(x[:])`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe But In the python shell, I am able to continually execute random.shuffle(x) and checking x after each call, x does get shuffled.

Comment: Yes, of course it does, I'm not saying otherwise. `k` actually contains the same sequence of `x` *shuffled*, but there are only so many unique orders so sometimes it *will* be the same as your starting position.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see! Now I'm understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @jonrsharpe, `random.shuffle` acts on the list in place. When you append `x`, you are appending the reference to that specific object. As such, at the end of the loop, `k` contains ten pointers to the same object!

To correct this, simply create a new copy of the list each iteration, as follows. This is done by calling `list()` when appending.

```
import random
x = [1,0,0,1,1]
k = []
for i in range(10):
     random.shuffle(x)
     k.append(list(x))
```

Answer (score 3):

One pythonic way to create new random-orderings of a list is not to shuffle in place at all. Here is one implementation:

```
[random.sample(x, len(x)) for _ in range(10)]
```

**Explanation**

- `random.sample` creates a new list, rather than shuffling in place.
- `len(x)` is the size of the sample. In this case, we wish to output lists of the same length as the original list.
- List comprehensions are often considered pythonic versus explicit for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x = [1,0,0,1,1]
k = []
for i in range(10):
     random.shuffle(x)
     k.append(x.copy())
return x
```

By replacing `x` with `x.copy()` you append to `k` a new list that looks like `x` at that moment instead of `x` itself.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what you've changed and why.